# Update result to TextView of AlertDialog Android

Tags: java, android, dialog, textview, alert

When I tried to set the result of my program to a textView in a dialog box , the app force closed. I made the dialog box by linking an xml which has a textview and it is this textview that I tried to update.

```
AlertDialog.Builder alert = new AlertDialog.Builder(this); 
    LayoutInflater factory = LayoutInflater.from(this);        
    resultOne=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.resultOne); //resultone is a textview in xml dialog

    resultOne.setText("hello");  //this code is making the app close

    final View textEntryView = factory.inflate(R.layout.dialog, null);
    alert.setView(textEntryView);
    alert.show();
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change the order so that you acess the View's children *after* inflating it. You will also need to use `textEntryView` to find the id, like so:

```
LayoutInflater factory = LayoutInflater.from(this);        
final View textEntryView = factory.inflate(R.layout.dialog, null);

resultOne=(TextView)textEntryView.findViewById(R.id.resultOne); //resultone is a textview in xml dialog

resultOne.setText("hello");
alert.setView(textEntryView);

alert.show();
```